# Удаление дочерних записей при удалении родительского

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eng_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Хотелось бы добавить такую функцию что если удаляется запись с id_parent = 0(т.е корень), то все дочерние элементы тоже удалялись, прочитал про ON DELETE CASCADE начал реализовывать, но как я понял там надо использовать 2 таблицы для этого, а если у меня всё в одной таблице как поступить, потому что когда я сделал эту связь, я больше не смог добавлять записи даже если таблица была пустой? У меня пока из мыслей только использовать 2 запроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобный функционал можно осуществить через `FOREIGN KEY`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

`ON DELETE CASCADE` - удалит данные из `child` таблицы если удалена строка из `parent` таблицы.

**пример:**

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Как правильно подметил @retvizan можно `FOREIGN KEY` делать на ту же таблицу.

**пример:**

```
CREATE TABLE just_table (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES just_table(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Совет:**

Не удаляйте записи, просто отмечайте их флагом как удаленные.

1. Удаление очень дорогая процедура. Кто то может вывести из строя ваше приложение просто добавив большое число детей к родителю и потом удалив запись родителя.
2. При ошибках вы можете случайно получить неполные данные.

Answer (score 1):

неправильно поняли, необязательно 2 таблицы:

```
alter table `tb_category` add foreign key (`id`) references `tb_category`(`id_parent`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```